# Config for tslint.json file in visual studio code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

My project is in typescript and i am using tslint extension for vscode.

I have disabled *no-var-keyword* and *prefer-const* because target for the js file would be IE9 users too. And it doesn't support `let` keyword so i am using `var` in whole project.

If i create a variable in `if` block and then use it in `else`, tslint doesn't give any error.

```
if(someVariable){
    var val="abc";
    // Some other code
}
else{
    val="def";
    // Some other code
}
```

This should give some error/warning but it doesn't, is there any option through which it can be enabled?

Below is my tslint.json

```
{
"defaultSeverity": "error",
"extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
],
"jsRules": {
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-unsafe-finally": true
},
"rules": {
    "indent": [
        true,
        "tab"
    ],
    "variable-name": [
        true,
        "ban-keywords",
        "check-format",
        "allow-leading-underscore"
    ],
    "prefer-const": false,
    "no-var-keyword": false,
    "only-arrow-functions": [false],
    "space-before-function-paren": [
        true,
        {
            "anonymous": "always",
            "named": "never",
            "asyncArrow": "always"
        }
    ],
    "curly": [true, "as-needed"],
    "no-empty": false,
    "one-variable-per-declaration": [false],
    "one-line": [true, "check-catch", "check-finally", "check-open-brace", "check-whitespace"]
},
"rulesDirectory": []
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use the transpile features the TypeScript compiler offers and target ES2015? Then const/let will be automatically transformed into something IE9 undestands too.

Comment: Regarding your issue: can you show us your tslint.json file? Is "use strict" on?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv That might work, i will try and see. Thanks...

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Included my tslint file and "use strict" isn't on.